# Application_Error isn't triggered in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How do I get the `Application_Error` triggered in an ASP.NET WebAPI application? The error I'm having now is that when we resolve a controller through NInject and fails it won't got into `Application_Error` and we can't log the error since we are doing the global logging in `Application_Error`.

We also have a global filter for handling error, but that is only triggered if we have found a controller but since we are failing we instantiating the controller we won't go through any filters.

So how do I catch an `Exception` raised why trying to create the controller handling the response?

Comment: If you'd like Application_Error (or something similar) implemented in the next version of Web API, please vote for the request I created at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1001

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net Web API has its own Exception Handler, you can override it and re-throw exception from there in order to handle it in `Application_Error`

```
public class MyExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public virtual Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(context.Exception).Throw();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

you also need to add `MyExceptionHandler` class to Web API services.

```
httpConfiguration.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyExceptionHandler());
```